# How do I retrieve the server address via a button

Tags: python, html

I execute my script in command line.
When I execute **./script.py server_adress param2 param3 param4** it opens a page with html form and a button, when we type on the button, I want to retrieve this server address.

that's a part of the code of the **script.py :**

```
import os, sys, platform, getpass, tempfile
import webbrowser
import string
import json


def main( server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path):

  template = open('scriptHmtl.phtml').read()

  contenu = string.Template(template).substitute(
            code_name = code_name,
            code_version = code_version,
            install_path = install_path,
            os = user_os,
            user_name = user_login
            )
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='/tmp/info.html', mode='w', delete=False)
f.write(contenu)
f.close()

webbrowser.open(f.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server_IP = sys.argv[1]
  code_name = sys.argv[2]
  code_version = sys.argv[3]
  install_path = sys.argv[4]

  user_os = sys.platform
  sys.argv.append(user_os)

  user_login = getpass.getuser()
  sys.argv.append(user_login)

  config_file = open("config.txt", "w")
  json.dump(sys.argv, config_file)

  main(server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path)
```

and here, the code html to get the address , **scriptHtml.py**

```
<html>
<body>
App: ${code_name}<br/><br/>

cv: ${code_version}<br/><br/>

path install: ${install_path}<br/><br/>

<form name="Data" method="get" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/><br/>
    First name: <input type="text" name="fn"/><br/><br/>
    Mail: <input type="text" name="mail"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py" -> I think the problem is here.

Comment: Before this degenerates into a discussion of web frameworks (they are all excellent) you have written your script as though the server would call it with the four arguments from the form. Sadly this is not the way the web works: you have to get the parameters from the URL. There are libraries to help, but first you should understand HTTP a bit more, I think. Then you will be able to better understand why Python web programs are the way they are and how to solve your problem.

Comment: One of the most basic things about the Web and one of it's most common protocols (**HTTP*)) is the Request and Response model. An Agent (*Browser*) makes a Request to an Origin Server (*Apache + mod_wsgi + your_wsgi_callable -- Some suitable Python Web Server / Framework*).

Comment: @holdenweb : When I execute my script : ./script.py param1 ... param4, it opens the webbrowser and display the fourth parameters in the web page ( this is what I wanted ).

Comment: The code as published does not appear to call the `main()` function, neither does it use the `browser` library, so it is hard to see how it is managing to bring anything up in your browser. Further, you don't appear to have a web server listening for the input from the form. That's what HTTP is for, after all, and browsers are still primarily HTTP clients. Or was this simply as far as you've got (which is fine, you have made an attempt) but it currently sounds like the form is displaying in your browser.

Comment: @Glacius I would recommend you ``pip install circuits`` and take my sample and learn from it. Then with more understanding can you ask more questions that we can help you with!

Comment: @holdenweb : I have edited the code .... that's the full code.

Comment: @JamesMills : I can not install module, I can only use the standard modules :(

Comment: @Glacius This is just simply not how the Web and HTTP work. You cannot post form data to a file!

Comment: Python libraries can be used without installation. Download, Extract and run from within the directory or add the directory to ``$PYTHONPATH`` or ``sys.path``.

Comment: @JamesMills : I don't want to post form data to a file, but only recover the server address when I type one the button ( example when I type on the button, we need to access on a new web page with the address server in the URL) , for the moment I have the localhost as URL , and that's not good.

Comment: @Glacius I'm sorry but we cannot help you if you can't help yourself. *We have tried*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you **really** want to do here is use a proper Python Web Framework.

CGI went out of fasion decdaes ago?

**Example:** (Using [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Forms

A simple example showing how to deal with data forms.
"""

from circuits.web import Server, Controller


FORM = """
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Basic Form Handling</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Basic Form Handling</h1>
  <p>
   Example of using
   <a href="http://circuitsframework.com/">circuits</a> and its
   <b>Web Components</b> to build a simple web application that handles
   some basic form data.
  </p>
  <form action="/save" method="POST">
   <table border="0" rules="none">
    <tr>
     <td>First Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="firstName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Last Name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="lastName"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan=2">
       <input type="submit" value="Save">
     </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>"""


class Root(Controller):

    def index(self):
        """Request Handler

        Our index request handler which simply returns a response containing
        the contents of our form to display.
        """

        return FORM

    def save(self, firstName, lastName):
        """Save Request Handler

        Our /save request handler (which our form above points to).
        This handler accepts the same arguments as the fields in the
        form either as positional arguments or keyword arguments.

        We will use the date to pretend we've saved the data and
        tell the user what was saved.
        """

        return "Data Saved. firstName={0:s} lastName={1:s}".format(
            firstName, lastName
        )


app = Server(("0.0.0.0", 8000))
Root().register(app)
app.run()
```

*Disclaimer:* I'm the developer of circuits.

**NB:** There are many other good Python Web Frameworks:

- [flask](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask)
- [bottle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle)
- [Django](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django)
- ... etc ...

Comment: So, I want to retrieve the server address (which I pass in parameter to the execution of the script) when I type on the button (it opens a new web page and when we type on the button I want to recover that's server address), I don't know if you understand me.

Comment: @Glacius You missing some vital background in Web Development and a basic understanding of HTTP. There is almost no reason I can think of for a form's submission URI be an absolute URI if we're posting data to the web application serving up the form.

Comment: yes, i'm novice, and now I thought to put server_IP = server_IP in contenu = string.Template(template).substitute( ) ... but the problem is in action ="" because I can't to put the localhost here.

Answer (score 0):

```
contenu = string.Template(template).substitute(
            code_name = code_name,
            code_version = code_version,
            install_path = install_path,
            os = user_os,
            user_name = user_login
            server_IP = http:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py
            )
```

scriptHtml.py

```
<form name="Data" method="get" action="${server_IP}">
```

that is something like that ?

Comment: you just put http:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py in server_IP , I have no tested your solution but I don't think it works.